# How to retrieve the full file extension from filenames with 2+ dots in CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

Say you have a filename that has more than 2 dots in it, such as `.symbols.nupkg`. If you have a Batch script like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo %~x1
```

and you run it with the file in question, it will give you only the `.nupkg` portion. Is there any way to get the full file extension from such a string?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: By definition, the extension is the portion from the last dot to the end of the name, so the extension of the file you've named is `.nupkg`. The rest is part of the file name, not the extension.

Comment: As per definition in Windows, the file extension is the part behind the *last* period `.`; anyway, to get everything from the first `.`, do `set "FILE=%~nx1"` (extract full file name), then `set "FILE=.%FILE:*.=%"` (variable `FILE` will hold the result)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, the *file extension* is defined to be the portion from the *last* period.

Anyway, if you do want to extract the portion from the *first* period, you could use the following code:

```
set "FILE=%~nx1"
set "FILE=.%FILE:*.=%"
echo("%FILE%"
```